# Iterating and keeping track of count

Tags: python, iterator, counter

I am trying to iterate through a bit of code with a delay and also keep count of the time it's run.

I believe I have to use a while loop and a sleep loop but I'm unsure as to how they'd look together.

```
def download_image():
    while True:
        try:
            image = requests.get(newmeme).content
        except requests.RequestError:
            print("Retrying downloading")
            time.sleep(2 * 60)
        else:
            break
    with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image)
    print("Download done.")

def upload_image(count):
    while True:
        try:
            twitter_API.update_with_media("image.jpg", status="dankmeme #{}".format(count))
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print("Retrying uploading")
            time.sleep(2 * 60)
        else:
            break
    print("Image #{} uploaded at {:%H:%M}".format(count, datetime.now()))


count = 0

while True:
        download_image()
    upload_image()
        count = count+1
        time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: At first glance, this code looks like it does what you want.  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Trying to use said count inside the defined functions. Do I need to define the function inside the loop?

```
https://i.redd.it/xyvcagscb8u21.jpg
Download done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacoby/Documents/dankmemes.py", line 65, in <module>
    upload_image()
TypeError: upload_image() missing 1 required positional argument: 'count'
```

Comment: You defined the `upload_image()` function to require an argument, but at the bottom of your code you are calling it without any argument.

Comment: Ahh that fixed it! Thanks!